# how to position container

Tags: html, css

I got and issue how to center my element in css.

I want set my header with background image width 100% and height 100% and some navigation, text/image div in my header as below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googlrapis.com/css?family=poppins:400,500,700');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.30);
}

.nav-background {
  background-image: url(http://localhost/newsystem/images/background.jpg);
  repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.header-contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.contain-one {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.50);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.header-contain img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav-background">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="header-contain">
      <img src="images/umbrella.png">
      <div class="contain-one">
        <h5>Let's start with us</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, est.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The issue is why my .header-container height start below my navigation. I want `.header-container` same size as my `.nav-background` image. So I can make my `.header-container` img fix to bottom of my div elements of nav-background.

Below is the image issue I facing now.

[image]

Comment: Background Image cannot be scaled as such. Its height will increase proportionate to width.

so try theese things: 1. set height to 100%. 
2. set background size option to cover, with center position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex on your container and make the header contain grow to fill the rest of the space instead of using height 100%:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googlrapis.com/css?family=poppins:400,500,700');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  /* add this */
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  margin:0;              /* add this */
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.30);
}

.nav-background {
  background-image: url(http://localhost/newsystem/images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: flex;          /* add this */
  flex-direction: column; /* aligns child items in a column */
}

.header-contain {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;           /* add this */
}

.contain-one {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.50);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.header-contain img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav-background">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="header-contain">
      <img src="images/umbrella.png">
      <div class="contain-one">
        <h5>Let's start with us</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, est.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Pete, you're Awesome!!!!.. thanks for your help..I need learn more about Flex :p

Comment: No problems, here are a couple of good links: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv